# Python: Accessing data packets sent one after the other

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the MPU-9150. It sends data packets of accelerometer data, gyroscope data, rotation data etc one at a time. To access the different data packets, I am using if statements `if self.type == 0 for accelerometer` and `if self.type == 5 for rotation`.

Now my problem is figuring out how to obtain both data packets because subsequent calculations require both to be available.

```
    self.readings = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    #if (self.type == 0) and (self.type == 5):

    #    print "Both data is available"
    counter = 0

    while counter < 1:

        if self.type == 0:
            print "TESTING FOR ACCELERATION"
            self.readings[0] = self.data[0]
            self.readings[1] = self.data[1]
            self.readings[2] = self.data[2]

        elif self.type == 5:
            print "TESTING FOR ROTATION MATRIX"
            self.readings[3] = self.data[0]
            self.readings[4] = self.data[1]
            self.readings[5] = self.data[2]
            self.readings[6] = self.data[3]
            self.readings[7] = self.data[4]
            self.readings[8] = self.data[5]
            self.readings[9] = self.data[6]
            self.readings[10] = self.data[7]
            self.readings[11] = self.data[8]

        else:
            print "None of the Conditions are True!"
            pass

        counter += 1

    aX = self.readings[0]
    aY = self.readings[1]
    aZ = self.readings[2]

    print 'Acc in X = ', aX
    print 'Acc in Y = ', aY
    print 'Acc in Z = ', aZ

    r1 = self.readings[3]
    r2 = self.readings[4]
    r3 = self.readings[5]
    r4 = self.readings[6]
    r5 = self.readings[7]
    r6 = self.readings[8]
    r7 = self.readings[9]
    r8 = self.readings[10]
    r9 = self.readings[11]

    print 'rotation matrix: \n%7.3f %7.3f %7.3f\n%7.3f %7.3f %7.3f\n%7.3f %7.3f %7.3f' % \
          (r1, r2, r3, \
           r4, r5, r6, \
           r7, r8, r9)
```

Running this code checks for `self.type == 0` and gives values of acceleration but retains zeros for rotation, then it gives values of rotation and zeros for acceleration.

When I logged the results from running the code, I obtained the results

```
TESTING FOR ACCELERATION 
Acc in X = -0.08056640625 
Acc in Y = -0.04541015625 
Acc in Z = 1.0068359375 
rotation matrix: 
0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 
TESTING FOR ROTATION MATRIX 
Acc in X = 0 
Acc in Y = 0 
Acc in Z = 0 
rotation matrix: 
0.980 0.178 0.085 
-0.181 0.983 0.030 
-0.078 -0.045 0.996 
TESTING FOR ACCELERATION 
Acc in X = -0.080078125 
Acc in Y = -0.044921875 
Acc in Z = 1.0068359375 
rotation matrix: 
0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 
etc
```

Comment: The `edit` button is there to let you make changes to your original question, rather than having to add comments.

Comment: Noted with thanks Martin

Comment: What is `self` referring to here? It looks like you are trying to put code into an object/type that doesn't belong there.

Comment: Self is declared in the constructor of the class (In the code that I did not post), it refers to the instantiated object of the class to which this method show above belongs.

Comment: Okay, I know how object orientation works in Python, I mean what is `self` referring to _here_, which type has it and what is this type supposed to represent within your program. It looks like it represents _one_ message but you are trying to process more then one message within a method of that single message type, which would be the wrong place conceptually.